# Z-Index Issues in the 10k Tools Flag Queue

Tags: bug, design, css

It looks like there's another issue with flagging in the 10k user tools. Here is what it looks like:

> [image: Flag Dialog]

As you can see, the container for the content seems to be the cutoff for where I can see the dialog. The background of the site seems to be above the flag dialog (which is bad).

Unlike the grey box issues over the buttons, this `<div>` doesn't seem to have a z-index property:

`<div id="popup-flag-post" class="popup" data-postid="19489" style="position: absolute; top: 1984px; left: calc(50% - 350px); display: block;">`

Comment: Similar to this, scrolling one notch too far in close queue hides the button below the site footer. Or if the post is too short the button is never visible (presumably because of the above issue)

Comment: Same in the review queue

Comment: Where are you seeing this in /review, @CMW? Screenshot + answer please?

Comment: @Shog9 http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/2475/layout-z-order-bug-when-flagging-questions